# Right path to ASP.NET MVC4 Controller's ActionMethod to use for ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have following MVC4 application structure:

[image: application structure]

From Index.cshtml i'm trying to make ajax call to SomeActionMethod(), situated in my HomeController.cs

Index.cshtml looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SomeActionMethod", "HomeController")',
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("fail");
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

HomeController.cs looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SapRepLanciatoreCAS.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //trying to invoke from ajax
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SomeActionMethod()
        {
            return Json(new { foo = "bar", baz = "Blech" });
        }
    }
}
```

When I start my application I got this error:
[image]

What's wrong with path or controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MVC takes first part of `controller` name into consideration i.e. disregards `Controller` keyword (see your view it is called `Home`). So your url should be - change `HomeController` to `Home`:

```
url: '@Url.Action("SomeActionMethod", "Home")',
```

Comment: I know it is frustrating, try tools such as Resharper and it would show view errors such as this ;)

Comment: This pattern in ASP.NET MVC kinda bugs me.

Answer (score 0):

```
url:'@Url("Method Name","Controller Name")'
```

Hope This will Help You.